# Read-only output when running "make all" in clion (WSL2)

Tags: makefile, clion, readonly, wsl-2

I want to run a project makefile (rule all) using the clion tool, but when I use it, it seems to work, but it gives me a read-only output. I've done the same thing on Ubuntu, and it works, but with WSL2, it's always a read only output.

[image: readonly output]

I tried to edit the config, but nothing I've done solved my issue.

[image: run configuration]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get CLion to *run* the built program interactively as part of the project *build*.  That's poor form, and I guess CLion does not support it. I'm not that familiar with CLion, but it is typical for IDEs to have a facility for running programs that is separate from their facility for building them.  That's what you should be engaging in CLion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger as I said, the same thing works on linux, with the same config. But here on WSL2 it does not. Thus, Clion support it but it seems like I have to do something extra for it to work on WSL2 too

Comment: WSL2 *is* Linux.  And that what you're trying to do happens to work as you want in one Linux environment does not imply that it's a good or appropriate thing to do.